# Extension methods and inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, extension-methods

At first, I have an extension method for DbContext class to save with logs :

```
public static int SaveChangesWithLogging(this DbContext context, NLog.Logger logger)
{
    //logging
    //[...]

    return context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then, I have a class which inherit from dbcontext and where I override SaveChanges()

```
public class ChildDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        //other stuff
        //[...]

        //doesn't work, no definition for SaveChangesWithLogging (extension method not found, why ?)
        return base.SaveChangesWithLogging();


        //doesn't work, loop on SaveChanges by extension method and stack overflow as a result
        return base.SaveChangesWithLogging();
    }
}
```

I want to call the SaveChanges() of base DbContext class, but it call SaveChanges() of ChildDbContext or I have a loop and a stack overflow...

What is the good solution ?

Comment: "I have a loop and a stack overflow..." What? Where is your loop? Or do you mean you have an endless recursion causing a `StackOverflowException`? Anyway your problem seems like XY-problem. Why are you calling `SaveChanges` from within `SaveChanges` at all? This seems like a broken design. You should not (and can´t) indicate which method to call in an inheritance-chain, it´s *allways* the most derived one. Doing something different would break OOP-principles.

Answer (score 1):

The extension method is hiding the *real* problem is that you're trying to call an overridden method from the outside, which is not possible.  Since the *actual* object is a `ChildDbContext`, the overridden method will be called by `SaveChangesWithLogging`.  There's not a way to call the "base" method from within `SaveChangesWithLogging` - even if you cast it before of after the method.

I suggest rearranging your call hierarchy so that the base method can be called from the derived method, or using non-virtual methods so that the base method can be called directly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use a wrapper for my dbcontext.